# How to specify a value for a Jenkins environment variable that contains a space

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I am trying to specify a value for a Jenkins environment variable (as created on the Manage Jenkins -> Configure System screen, under the heading "Global properties") which contains a space. I want to use this environment variable in an Execute Shell build step. The option that I need to appear in the command line in the build step is:

```
--platform="Windows 7"
```

The syntax I am using on the command line is `--platform=${VARIABLE_NAME}`

No matter how I attempt to format it, Jenkins seems to reformat it so that it is treated as two values. I have tried:

- Windows 7
- "Windows 7"
- 'Windows 7'
- Windows\ 7

The corresponding results, when output during the Execute Shell build step have been:

- --platform=Windows 7
- '--platform="Windows' '7"'
- '--platform='\''Windows' '7'\'''
- --platform=Windows/ 7

I have also tried changing my command line syntax to `--platform='${VARIABLE_NAME}'` as well as `'--platform=${VARIABLE_NAME}'`, but in each of those cases the `${VARIABLE_NAME}` is not resolved at all and just appears as `${VARIABLE_NAME}` on the resulting command.

I am hoping there is a way to make this work. Any suggestions are most appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use spaces without any special characters in the global properties section.

For example, I set a variable "THIS_VAL" to have the value "HAS SPACES".

My test build job was the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +v
echo ${THIS_VAL}
echo "${THIS_VAL}"
echo $THIS_VAL
```

and the output was

```
[workspace] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson8126983335734936805.sh
HAS SPACES
HAS SPACES
HAS SPACES
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I think what you need to do is use the following:

```
--platform="${VARIABLE_NAME}"
```

**NOTE: Use *double* quotes, not single quotes**. Using single quotes makes the stuff inside the quotes literal, meaning that any variables will be printed as is, not parsed into the actual value. Therefore '${VARIABLE_NAME}' will be printed as is, not parsed into "Windows 7".

---

**EDIT:**
Based on @BobSilverberg comment below, use the following:

```
--platform="$VARIABLE_NAME"
```

Note: no curly brackets.

Comment: Thank you Sagar. Out of all the combinations I tried, that wasn't one of them. It did end up working, but I had to specify `--platform="$VARIABLE_NAME"`. If I used `--platform="${VARIABLE_NAME}"` it snuck some extra quotes in there, so the result was `'--platform='\''Windows 7'\'''`.